# Two lists, 1 has passwords and 2 has usernames. how can the program only allow access if both the first (or second or third) items are used

Tags: python

```
dic(zip(['example@example.co.uk','thing@thing.co.uk','email@email.co.uk'],
['Games','English','Piano']
```

How do I tell the computer that the account can only be accessed if both the first email and first password are entered, instead of first email and second password or third password, and only if both are entered correctly too. (Same with second email and password, and third etc)?

Comment: `login_succeeded = dict[user_name]==password`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the passwords as strings (it's not very safe), you could try this (Python 3):

```
passwords = dict(zip(['example@example.co.uk','thing@thing.co.uk','email@email.co.uk'], ['Games','English','Piano']))

#Get password from user (an example for console, please use a safer way)
email = input("Enter your e-mail adress: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

try:
    if passwords[email] == password:
        #log in
    else:
        print("This password is wrong")
except KeyError:
    print("This account does not exist")
```